# Not able to access website with CNAME(alias) on host machine from container

Tags: docker, windows-container

I have a windows VM and on that I have docker installed, also on that VM I have a website(other than Default Website) on https and have a CNAME(alias) defined in DNS.

I execute the *docker run --name msbuild --detach --interactive --net=d2b69795fdc5 firstimage* to create the image and able to access the *default website* from powershell command *Invoke-WebRequest 172.24.0.1/abc.html -UseBasicParsing* where 172.24.0.1 is the ip of my host machine allotted by NAT created by docker.

Site bindings for the website are as follows
*http:*:80:.test.local,https:*:443:CNAME.test.local*

The issue is I am able to get the *Default Website* but cannot access the website *CNAME.test.local*
I understand that the problem is its not able to get to Domain Controller to get the info about the CNAME and it doesnt works if I add *--dns="My DNS Server Name" *
in the commandlien to start the container
Is there any way to access this website?